# Creating a list instead of an array

Tags: python, list

I'm very new to Python and I'm not even sure whether I worded the title correctly. I'm trying to get a dataset with two years of statistics (one below the other). This is not working because the "table" variable is an array, I believe, where each year's data is its own element. If I remove two lines of codes (specified below as "Line1" and "Line2" I do get both years but without the right shape, however; I use the "thm" variable's length to to determine the number of rows in an year and then use numpy's reshape function before I append it to the "table" variable. Thanks.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table=[]

for i in range(1956,1958):
  url="https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_{}.html#stats::none".format(i)

  soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")

  thm=[]
  for tag in soup.find_all("tr"):
    list=tag.find("th", class_="right")
    if list:
      thm.append(list.text)

  mtable1=[]
  trs=soup.find_all("tr")
  for tr in trs:
    tds=tr.find_all("td")
    for td in tds:
      mtable1.append(td.text)

  #Line1
  mtable2=[mtable1]
  #Line2
  mtable3=np.reshape(mtable2,[len(thm),21])

  table.append(mtable3)

data=pd.DataFrame(table)

data.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I only had to convert the array into a list and then extend the list into the subsequent years through iteration.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table=[]

for i in range(1956,1958):
  url="https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_{}.html#stats::none".format(i)

  soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")

  #Obtaining table's headers
  tag1=soup.find_all("tr")[1]
  header=[]
  for tag in tag1.find_all("th"):
    list1=tag.text
    if list1:
     header.append(list1)
  header=header[1:]
  #Creating another column for the year of the draft
  header.append("Year")

  thm=[]
  for tag in soup.find_all("tr"):
    list=tag.find("th", class_="right")
    if list:
      thm.append(list.text)

  mtable1=[]
  trs=soup.find_all("tr")
  for tr in trs:
    tds=tr.find_all("td")
    for td in tds:
      mtable1.append(td.text)

  mtable2=[mtable1]
  mtable3=np.reshape(mtable2,[len(thm),21])
  mtable4=mtable3.tolist()
  for row in mtable4:
    row.append(i)
  table.extend(mtable4)

data=pd.DataFrame(table, columns=header)
data.to_csv("data.csv")
```